# Pairing a name from one text file with a random name from the same text file

Tags: python, text, lines, names

I have a text file with 20 names stored (although in practice it will be more than 20)

Each name is stored on separate line eg.

```
Joe
Bob
James
Hannah
Ella
```

I want my script to pair each of the names with another name.

The purpose of the exercise is for pairing people for practice matches in fencing so that it is completely random.

The output should be written to another file at the end of the script eg. a text file containing 10 pairs of names.

I am new to python and have never used it in this way.

So far I am thinking of storing a list of the names using

```
with open(names.txt) as f:
    names = f.readlines()
```

then after that I expect the best way would be to iterate through the lines using

```
for name in names:
```

however after that I am stumped. I know at this point I have one name out of a list of names and that will be used for the rest of `for` loop and then the 2nd name will be used when it repeats. However I can't work out how to match the name to another random name in the list.

I could just iterate through backwards starting on the last line but that's not random and just matches the first to the last, and then 2nd to penultimate etc.

How can I make the pairing random?

Comment: With [`random`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The python way would be to shuffle the list and then extract pairs from it:

```
from random import shuffle

with open('names.txt', 'r') as f:
    names = [name.strip() for name in f]

shuffle(names)

pairs = zip(names[::2], names[1::2])
```

`names[::2]` are the names in odd positions (counting from 0) and `names[1::2]` are the ones in even positions. Check also the documentation for [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip). After that you can iterate over pairs and write them to file:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for pair in pairs:
        f.write('%s is paired with %s\n' % pair)
```

### Even better

It's not your case but if you need to be even faster without saving temporary structure, you could `from itertools import izip` and then after the shuffle:

```
it = iter(names)
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for pair in izip(it, it):
        f.write('%s is paired with %s\n' % pair)
```

Comment: This works fantastically however I do encounter a couple of issues. When printing the list the first name is always followed be `\xa0` and when I try to write to a file using    `with open('pairs.txt', 'w') as f: for pair in pairs: f.write(pair)`    I get the error message `"TypeError: expected a character buffer object"`

Comment: Of course... I've spent too long using python purely for parsing xml and just editing stuff, seems I forgot the basics of writing to files!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use `random.shuffle` to change the order of the names:

```
In [11]: names  = ["Joe","Bob","James","Hannah","Ella"]

In [12]: random.shuffle(names)

In [13]: names
Out[13]: ['Bob', 'Ella', 'James', 'Joe', 'Hannah']
```

I

```
n [21]: import random

In [22]: from itertools import izip

In [23]: names  = ["Joe","Bob","James","Hannah","Ella","Foo"]

In [24]: random.shuffle(names)

In [25]: for name1,name2 in izip(*[iter(names)]*2):
   ....:          print name1,name2
   ....:     
Ella Foo
James Hannah
Joe Bob
```

Comment: and then I can just call define a variable `name1` as the name in the first list and `name2` as the name in the 2nd list and then just do `f.write(name1 + 'is paired with' + name2)`

Comment: if you only want to use each name once, just use `random.choice` and pop the names off the list

Comment: I think this does not work, since e.g. ```Bob``` might get paired with himself, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: The shuffled list could be ```['Ella', 'Bob', 'James', 'Joe', 'Hannah']```. If matching each name of the original list with a name of the shuffled list, ```Bob``` is matched with ```Bob```. (```James``` is actually matched with ```James``` as well.)

Comment: @Falko unless Bob is in there twice I don't see how that would happen, if shuffling do it once and match the names in pairs

Comment: Yeah ok, I guess I got your pairing approach wrong. So basically you'd ```zip``` it like enrico.bacis, which is a pretty neat solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Random` class as documented here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html
If you want to grab the names pairwise you can do so by getting one element out of the list at random, then getting a second out of the (now smaller) list:

```
while len(names) > 0:
    first = names.pop(random.randint(0, len(names)-1))
    second = names.pop(random.randint(0, len(names)-1))
    # Write those out to your result file in whatever format you want
```

Comment: It's better to use `while names:` instead of `while len(names) > 0:`

Comment: Thanks, I've been writing too much C# recently and "forgot" that Python lets you test objects for Boolean values.

Comment: You probably need to check ```while len(names) > 1```, since ```names``` can be of odd length.